# AngularFire: Checkboxes Don't Work

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've got a form with a text field and a few checkboxes. It works perfectly fine if I fill out the `<input type="text">` field first, but if I mark the checkboxes first, the checkboxes aren't passed to my function on `ng-submit()`.

**HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="createService(service)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="service.name" required>
  <div ng-repeat="provider in providers">
    <md-checkbox id="{{ provider }}" ng-model="service.providers[provider.$id]">{{ provider.name }}</md-checkbox>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="h4 button button-big mb4" aria-label="Add Service">Add Service</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.createService = function(service) {
  var checkedProviders = {};
  var serviceProviders = service.providers;

  for (var checked in serviceProviders) {
    if (serviceProviders[checked]) {
      checkedProviders[checked] = true;
    }
  }

  services.$add({
    name: service.name,
    providers: checkedProviders
  });
};
```

It's very weird and I can't work out why it is doing this. Any help on why this is happening is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using standard checkboxes and not md-checkbox.

Comment: Tried it with standard checkboxes. Same issue.

Comment: What does `$scope.providers` look like?